# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '

Tags: php

Estou com um erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MedicaValidade'

```
 Trabalhador (1) Validade:';
If (($exibe['MedicaValidade'] != 0000-00-00) && ((strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()))) {
echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
echo 'Anexo: <a href="MostrarMedica.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF  </a>'
} elseif ((strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) >= time()) {
echo '.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].';
echo 'PDF: <a href="MostrarMedica.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF  </a>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Erros:*** *tem aspas entre '0000-00-00', aspas faltando e terminador de linha(`;`) faltando*.

```php
if ($exibe['MedicaValidade'] != '0000-00-00')
{
   if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) 
   {
        echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
        echo 'Anexo: <a href="MostrarMedica.php?id='. $exibe['id'].'">Ver PDF</a>';
   } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
        echo 'PDF: <a href="MostrarMedica.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">Ver PDF</a>';
   }
}
```

Comment: tenho este erro na linha do Elseif  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: @user3253195, pronto, editada!

Comment: O que alterou? Pois agora tenho o mesmo erro na linha {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
        echo 'PDF: <a href="MostrarMedica.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF  </a>';
    }

Comment: fiz outra edição melhorando, agora verifique se vai!

Comment: Tenho o mesmo erro agora na segunda { .. estava a perguntar para tentar corrigir.

Comment: @user3253195 olhe de novo